# Custom list item background wrapped around floated element

Tags: css

I have an issue when using a custom list image/ where the icon is getting hidden behind the floated element which the list wraps around.

http://jsfiddle.net/V8evM/

HTML

```
<div>

</div>
<ul>
    <li>This is list item no 1</li>
    <li>This is list item no 2. This is list item no. This is list item no. This is list item no. This is list item no. This is list item no. This is list item no.</li>
    <li>This is list item no 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
div {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 0
}

li {
  padding-left: 1.3em ;
}

li:before {
  content: "i";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
  width: 1.3em;
}
```

NOTE: I do not want to add extra mark, CSS only.

I have tried without the negative margin (http://jsfiddle.net/9qWGE/) but this causes the long list to appear under the icon

Comment: use float:left and  for ul and use to li text-overflow:ellipsis or word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/V8evM/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul {
    display: table; /* or table-cell */ 
}
```

`table`: *Behaves like the `<table>` HTML element. It defines a block-level box.*

[**Source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

http://jsfiddle.net/PWQZS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Work on the ul element, ajusting your margin and padding.

```
ul {
    padding-left:10px; /* fit this number to your needs */
    margin-left:111px; /* fit this number to your needs */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8m46/